# How to to run ajax request in loop only on success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my my scenario, first I'm getting the match result from ajax, then pass the each player ID to the next function to get their name. This is my code, what i expect is ID 1 -> ID 1 player name, but since ajax is async, what i get from the result are all in wrong order. However if i set the second function async:false, then it takes really long time to get all result.

```
var getCurrentMatch = function(playerID) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"url1",
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data){
        $.each( data.participants, function( index, player ) {
            getChampionInfo(player.championId);
        });
    }
  });
};
var getChampionInfo = function(championID) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"url2",
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data[championID]);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: don't think there is an issue here. It's the purpose of AJAX to make things async...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think where is an issue here.

On your first success function (for url1 AJAX call), you have to choices :

- Parallels calls: You loop for each player and make a call. In this case all call will be in the same time and the replies will NOT arrive ordered, but just randomly end when done.
- Series calls: In this case, you loop for each player and make a call only for the first one. When you receive the reply, you take the 2de player and make a request...

The second case is very more long to get all done cause you chain their. If a single call is done in 5sec, all call will be done in 5-10sec on parallel, but if you have 10 (or 100) players you have to wait 50s (or 500s => more than 8min !)

To do it more easily, I suggest you to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. You will be able to do both method [eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) (in serie) or [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) (in parallel) method (you can also mix with [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) (example: make parallel for the first 5 players, and wait for result to make others calls but never more than 5)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like `url2` contains all of the data for the looped requests. Don't loop them, make a request for the list of participants, then make a request for the champions. Then loop through to get the data needed.

```
var tmpParticipants;
var tmpChampions;

var getCurrentMatch = function(playerID) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"url1",
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data){
        tmpParticipants = data;
        getChampionInfo();
    }
  });
};
var getChampionInfo = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"url2",
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data){
        tmpChampions = data;
        $.each( tmpParticipants, function( index, player ) {
            tmpParticipants[index]["championId"] = tmpChampions[index].championId;
            // of course, this is dependent on how your data is structured 
            // so you may have to massage it differently
        });
    }
  });
};
```

This could be cleaned up quite a bit with [Deferreds and Promises](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics), but that's another question.